# How to count string length, if length equals X, then execute code? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function, string-length, onkeyup

Using JavaScript, I want to call an anonymous function that checks the length of a string for every onkeyup event. When the string length equals 9, a conditional statement will execute a block of code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<input type="text" id="length_test" placeholder="Enter text here..." />

var length_test = document.getElementById('length_test');
var string_value = document.getElementById('length_test').value;
var x = 9;

length_test.onkeyup = function () {
        if (string_value.length == x) {
        // execute code here...
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to define `string_value ` in the function so it's updated when the compare is made

Comment: Your code only fetches the value of the input element once. Move that line where you set "string_value" to inside the "keyup" handler.

Comment: essentially, `if(length_test.value.length == x)` since in all browsers, your first line does nothing...

Comment: Awesome Pointy! That worked. And thanks dandavis for the explanation, that helped to drive the concept home. This is my first question asked on Stack Overflow, I typically get the answer I need from browsing the pages. I can't wait to contribute. I appreciate all those with input. Power to the Programmers!

Answer (score 1):

Give the following a try.

Note:  The example below uses JQuery.  If you didn't wait to use JQuery that is fine.

You could natively do it with the following.

`document.getElementById("length_test").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);`

You would need to then create a function called myFunction that has your if statement in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#length_test").on("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.currentTarget.value.length == 9) {
        //do your logic here
        alert("length is 9");
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="length_test" placeholder="Enter text here..." />
```

Comment: This uses the JQuery library, which definitely isn't required for this. JQuery isn't everything.

Comment: Thats fine, but it is a solution for the poster.  It could be easily modified not to use Jquery.  Thats not a reason to downvote something.

Comment: It's a good answer but jQuery isn't tagged in the question and you didn't clearly point out this is using jQuery for those who are new to using javascript so yes it is worthy of being down voted.

Comment: I should have suggested an edit instead of downvoting, my bad. I just don't want newbies to use JQuery when they most probably don't need it. It doesn't make you learn how JS really works and it can slow down your code a lot.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I couldn't agree more! I like using pure javascript so I have a better understand of what's going on. Don't get me wrong, jQuery can be a great cheat sheet / time saver but I will avoid it if I want to have a great understanding of how something functions.

Comment: Valid, JQuery is nice in cases of IE browsers were they natively don't support some functions thought or implementation is not performant...  Double edged sword...

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` returns a live node. This means that any changes happening to the actual element in the page will be reflected on the object. When you write something else in the field, the `value` property of the element gets updated. However, the value stored in `string_value` doesn't get updated, since it's just a good old string, not some kind of live object.

Another way to see it is that
`var string_value = document.getElementById('length_test').value;`
makes a copy of the element's `.value` and stores it in `string_value` (even though that's not exactly how it works). When you type in the input, it updates the `.value` but not the `string_value` variable.

But what you should do is:

```
document.getElementById('length_test').addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.target.value.length === 9) {
    alert("length is 9");
  }
});
```

This is much better because `document.getElementById` is only executed once, when binding the event. Event listener functions can revieve the event through their first argument (commonly named `e`). `e.target` is the element which called the event, in this case the input element.

Comment: So in this example, the action is all happening inside the function without the need for an external variable, correct?

Comment: That's right, though you might want to save it in a global variable anyway if you want to use it outside of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<input type="text" id="length_test" placeholder="Enter text here..." onkeyup="keyupFunction()">
<script type = "text/javascript">
    keyupFunction function () {
        if(document.getElementById('length_test').value == 9) {
            // execute code here...
        }
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively,  you could use javascript to add an event listener to the input element:

```
<input type="text" id="length_test" placeholder="Enter text here...">
<script type = "text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('length_test').addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        if(document.getElementById('length_test').value == 9) {
            // execute code here...
        }
    });
</script>
```